# want to schedule call back automatically

Tags: asterisk

I am using queues for different options I want if customer leave their number it will automatically call if agent is available

this is for asterisk server.

```
[macro-ANSWERTIME]
exten => s,1,Noop(http://127.0.0.1/ivr/action/update_Queue_callback.php?process=3&unique_id=${unique_id}&caller_id=${callerNum}&queue=${campName}&Stime=${Stime})
exten => s,n,Set(UpAns=${SHELL(/usr/bin/curl "http://127.0.0.1/ivr/action/update_Queue_callback.php?process=3&unique_id=${unique_id}&caller_id=${callerNum}&queue=${campName}&Stime=${Stime}")})
exten => s,n,MacroExit()
```

It's not directing automatically.

Answer (score 0):

For that you need dialling core.

Write your own dialler core is bad idea if you beginner.

Use already writed opensource dialler(vicidal.org?) or hire someone who able do core for you(costly)

If you still want spent your time, read this first https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-auto-dial-out/

Comment: i am getting inbound calls in voicemail so i want to fetch caller id from the incoming call and dial the number automatically when agent is available

Comment: And? What problem you get here?

Comment: so could you please share me dialplan for this thanks in advance

Comment: please do our work by your own. I only answer qeustions which can  be answered in 1/2 screen size